# Handling 1,50,000 threads in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

while performance testing an application, i was unable to proceed further of handling large number of threads using JMeter, so, i would like to know the max number of threads that are allowed in Jmeter, Is jmeter capable of handling 1,50,000 threads?

Comment: Is that 1 million or 100 thousand?

Answer (score 3):

There is no upper limit, it strongly depends on what your test is doing, what is response size, etc.

Also keep in mind that real users don't hammer the application nonstop, they need some time to "think" between operations plus they have to wait for response before they start "thinking" about next action.

For example, given users "think" for 10 seconds and response time is 2 seconds it means that each virtual user will execute 5 requests per minute.

In above scenario 1 50 000 users will execute 7 50 000 requests per minute - which is 12 500 requests per second - > 10x times less users to simulate.

So:

- first of all make sure that your JMeter configuration is optimal, default settings are good for tests development and debugging but not very good for the load test execution. You need to

  - tune Java parameters (Heap size, GC, etc.)
  - disable all listeners
  - make sure that you have only those assertions and post processors which are absolutely required
  - you store only those metrics you need and you don't save any excessive results, especially response data

  [See 9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/9-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure) article for above points comprehensive explanation and some more tips

  - Even given you apply above tweaks I don't think you'll be able to conduct the load of 1 50 000 users from a single host (unless you have a supercomputer in your QA Lab) so I expect you'll need to consider [JMeter Distributed Testing](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_distributed_testing_step_by_step.pdf) when one master machine orchestrates multiple load generators aka "slaves" acting as a single instance - this way you will be able to increase the load by factor equal to number of slaves

Answer (score 0):

Yes Of course, it depends a lot on the machine running Jmeter, but if mileage counts I can give you some hints.

- JMeter allows you to run multiple processes in the same box, and it's usually pretty reliable generating up to 200-300 threads per JMeter instance. If you need more than that, I'd recommend using multiple JMeter instances
- Use below link for better description how Jmeter can handle 1,50,000 threads of multiple instances
- https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-load-test-50k-concurrent-users